# AFNetworking concurrent Http requests

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa, connection, httprequest

I need to download around 200 Files from an API. They are all only around 15KB.
My current code looks likes this:

```
NSOperationQueue* opQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
[opQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:8];

NSString* baseUrl = @"https://someapi.com/somejson.json?page=";

for(int n = 0; n <= numberOfPages; n++) {
    @autoreleasepool {

         NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", baseUrl, n]]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20];


        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Done");
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }];

        [opQueue addOperation:operation];

    }
};
```

While this is working fine, i am curious if there is a faster way to do this. It currently takes about 20 seconds to download the files. Since they are all that small, i guess what takes the most time is waiting for the server response. Is there a better way of queueing them, so all the connections are established at the "same" time, or is that just kind of a hardcap?

I already tried setting

```
[opQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:8];
```

to all kinds of different values, as well as not setting it at all. But that doesn't seem to really improve the performance.

This is a Charles log for one of the connections. The other ones are pretty much the same, but i can post more if necessary.

```
URL https://<hidden>&page=0
Status  Complete
Response Code   200 OK
Protocol    HTTP/1.1
Method  GET
Kept Alive  No
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Client Address  /127.0.0.1
Remote Address  <hidden>
Timing  
Request Start Time  24.02.15 09:49:58
Request End Time    24.02.15 09:49:58
Response Start Time 24.02.15 09:49:59
Response End Time   24.02.15 09:49:59
Duration    1.18 sec
DNS 1 ms
Connect 42 ms
SSL Handshake   127 ms
Request 0 ms
Response    1 ms
Latency 974 ms
Speed   8,36 KB/s
Response Speed  9.626,95 KB/s

Size    
Request Header  283 bytes
Response Header 552 bytes
Request -
Response    9,09 KB (9306 bytes)
Total   9,90 KB (10141 bytes)
Request Compression -
Response Compression    91,8% (gzip)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AFHTTPRequestOperation` uses bare bone `NSURLConnection`. I doubt there is anything you can do to improve server response time from the client side. However, there is a lot to be done on a server side:

1. Just pack the files in a single archive if it's possible.
2. The attached response headers state that the server disabled support for [persistent HTTP connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection):

> Kept Alive  No

Enabling keep-alive might be the best thing you can do.  Disabled persistent connections are [even worse](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/26/https-and-connection-close-is-your-apache-modssl-server-configuration-set-to-slow.aspx) for https than for http:

> Defeating HTTP/1.1’s default Keep-Alive behavior is a bad practice for regular HTTP connections but it’s far worse for HTTPS connections because the initial setup costs of a HTTPS connection are far higher than a regular HTTP connection. Not only does the browser pay the performance penalty of setting up a new TCP/IP connection, including the handshake and initial congestion window sizing, but the request’s progress is also penalized by the time required to complete the HTTPS handshake used to secure the connection.

3. And the last thing is [HTTP pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining). Make sure to check whether your server supports it. Then enable it on your requests:

   ```
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = ...
   request.HTTPShouldUsePipelining = YES;
   ```

Comment: since its not my own server, i sadly cannot do optimizations there. I tried the enabling of pipelining, but i guess, as long as the connection isn't kept alive, pipelining is not possible per definition?

Comment: oh and another thing, is there a way to check from outside if a server enabled keep-alive and pipelining?

Comment: The server will add "Connection: Keep-Alive" in response http headers.

Comment: i see, thank you! i will accept your answer, as it was very helpful in understanding the "bottleneck" here. However i will wait until the end of the bounty period, till i award the bounty to you

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the latency is the major contributor to the duration taken up to get a response to the request. One possible reason could be use of Proxy network. Also note that its not just the latency there is time taken to Connect, SSL Handshake which are also contributing to the `Duration    1.18 sec`.

Comment: sorry, but that doesn't answer my question. I asked about the possibility of code improvements, not for explanation of the Charles log file.

Answer (score 0):

The better is not set [opQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:8];

Actually, you have 8 process will start at a same time. If you don't set it, you will have more.

Comment: Sadly, there is no performance increase in doing so. Still takes the same amount of time.

Comment: So, you should debug your API time calling by Charles. The perform will increase but it not increase 1 or 2 second like you think, I mean it just increase miliseconds. Actually, if the low-performance cause by API timeout, there's no way to improve performance by changing your code.

Comment: ah ok, i see. I added a Charles log file to my question. As far as i can tell, the problem seems to be in the latency, which takes up most of the duration. Maybe you could take a look at the log? Thx so far!